# Geotechnical engineering: The $\phi=0$ concept

Tags: geotechnical-engineering, soil-mechanics

I am reading B.M. Das' book: Principles of Geotechnical Engineering, 6th edn. In the chapter concerning shear strength of soil the $\phi =0$-concept is introduced.[[image: The <span class=]$\phi=0$-concept" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7aie.jpg)

In an unconsolidated-undrained triaxial test of a soil specimen the Mohr's circles in the above picture can be drawn, where Q is effective stress' and P and R are total stress' under different chamber pressures $\sigma_3$. As I understand it it doesn't matter what chamber preassre $\sigma_3$ that is applied because the effective pressures will remain the same as all increases in chamber pressure will be resisted by the increasing pore water pressure. Hence the Mohr circle for effective stress $\sigma_1',\sigma_3'$ in circle Q is the same for both total pressure in P and R.

The book defines the shear stress strength $\tau_f$ for $\phi=0$ as $C_u$ which is the undrained shear strength (the horizonttaly dotted line that tangents all circles at the top).
What I don't understand why this value is used for shear strength since the failure for the specimens occur at the lower effective normal stress where the line with slope angle $\phi'$ tangents the circle Q which happens att a lower shear and normal stress than $C_u$

Answer (score 0):

because that sloped line is not for the undrained condition. only the horizontal envelope is for undrained condition.